# Use X,Y coordinates to plot points inside a circle

Tags: javascript, plot, coordinates, geometry

Is there a way in javascript to plot x,y coordinates so they fall into a circle rather than a square?

For example if I have the following code:

```
  circleRadius = 100;
  context.drawImage(img_elem, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

I need to figure out a combination of x,y values that would fall inside a 100 pixel circle.

Thanks!

Comment: The set of _(x, y)_ points within a circle of radius _r_ is given by the inequality _x^2 + y^2 < r^2_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. choose an x at random between -100 and 100
2. a circle is defined by `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`, which in your case equals 100^2 = 10000
3. From this equation you can get that `y^2 = 10000 - x^2` , therefore the points with a chosen x and `y = +/-sqrt(10000 - x^2)` will lye on the circle.
4. choose an y at random between the two coordinates found at point 3
5. You're set!

**EDIT:**
In JS:

```
var radius = 100;
x = Math.random() * 2 * radius - radius;
ylim = Math.sqrt(radius * radius - x * x);
y = Math.random() * 2 * ylim - ylim;
```

**Another edit:** [a jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6hvc70jj/3/)

Comment: Just playing around with it a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/YL6Bj/1/ - note that points tend to cluster on the extremes in the x direction, due to the fact that there is less choice for the y in those areas. If you need lots of points you may need to correct for that introducing a bias in the generation of the x coordinates.

Comment: Yes, this gives a very poor distribution. I added an answer with equidistributed results.

Comment: Well, the solution works very well for most situations, there was no need to downvote ...

Comment: I've made it into a fiddle and added that

Answer (score 3):

If you want equidistributed coordinates you better go for

```
var radius = 100
var center_x = 0
var center_y = 0

// ensure that p(r) ~ r instead of p(r) ~ constant
var r = radius*Math.sqrt(Math.random(1))
var angle = Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI)

// compute desired coordinates
var x = center_x + r*Math.cos(angle);
var y = center_y + r*Math.sin(angle);
```

If you want more points close to the middle then use

```
var r = radius*Math.random(1)
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

not sure what you mean for javascript but

`x = R*cos(theta)` and `y = R*sin(theta)` are the Cartesian points for a circle. R is the radius of course and theta is the angle which goes from 0 to 2*Pi.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a solution because this question was the only relevant result in google.

My question/problem was how to add cartesian coordinates inside a circle where `x` and `y` would not exceed `r`.

Examples:

1. plot: (45,75) inside a circle with a radius of 100 (this would normally fall inside the circle, but not the correct position)
2. plot: (100,100) inside a circle with a radius of 100 (this would normally fall outside the circle

Solution

```js
// The scale of the graph to determine position of plot
// I.E. If the graph visually uses 300px but the values only goto 100
var scale = 100; 

// The actual px radius of the circle / width of the graph
var radiusGraph = 300; 

// Plot the values on a cartesian plane / graph image
var xCart = xVal * radiusGraph;
var yCart = yVal * radiusGraph;

// Get the absolute values for comparison
var xCartAbs = Math.abs( xCart );
var yCartAbs = Math.abs( yCart );

// Get the radius of the cartesian plot
var radiusCart = Math.sqrt( xCart * xCart + yCart * yCart );

// Compare to decide which value is closer to the limit
// Once we know, calculate the largest possible radius with the graphs limit. 
// r^2 = x^2 + y^2
if ( xCartAbs > yCartAbs ) { // Less than 45°
    diff = scale / xCartAbs;
    radiusMaximum = Math.sqrt( radiusGraph * radiusGraph + Math.pow( yCartAbs * diff, 2) );
} else if ( yCartAbs > xCartAbs ) { // Greater than 45°
    diff = scale / yCartAbs;
    radiusMaximum = Math.sqrt( radiusGraph * radiusGraph + Math.pow( xCartAbs * diff, 2) );
} else { // 45°
    radiusMaximum = Math.sqrt( 2 * ( radiusGraph * radiusGraph ) );
}

// Get the percent of the maximum radius that the cartesian plot is at
var radiusDiff = radiusCart / radiusMaximum;
var radiusAdjusted = radiusGraph * radiusDiff;

// Calculate the angle of the cartesian plot
var theta = Math.atan2( yCart, xCart );

// Get the new x,y plot inside the circle using the adjust radius from above
var xCoord = radiusAdjusted * Math.cos( theta );
var yCoord = radiusAdjusted * Math.sin( theta );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct JavaScript code, but something like this:

```
for (x = -r; x < r; x++) {
  for (y = -r; x < r; y++) {
    if ((x * x + y * y) < (r * r)) {
      // This x/y coordinate is inside the circle.
      // Use <= if you want to count points _on_ the circle, too.
    }          
  }
}
```