# Calculating random x,y coordinate within circle

Tags: objective-c, math

How do I calculate random points inside a circle (somewhat evenly distributed)?

I have found this answer (the one by Udo Klein): [Use X,Y coordinates to plot points inside a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707796/use-x-y-coordinates-to-plot-points-inside-a-circle) and my Objective C implementation looks like this:

```
-(CGPoint)getRandomPointInCircle:(CGPoint)cCenter radius:(float)cRadius {
    float r = cRadius * sqrtf(arc4random());
    float angle = sqrtf(2 * M_PI);
    float x = cCenter.x + r * cosf(angle);
    float y = cCenter.y + r * sinf(angle);
    CCLOG(@"--> rand point: %f,%f", x, y);
    return ccp(x,y);
}
```

Now with a given circle with center 5000,5000 and radius of 7100 it gives me crazy values like this:
-324893408.000000,239372544.000000

please help a math fool :)

/Søren

Comment: Seems to me you need a random angle.  And, of course, your RNG needs to generate a float between 0 and 1, vs between 0 and 2 billion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't put `arc4random`'s output into a range, but you also didn't randomise the angle.

First, the mathematics of a random distribution within a circle:

For each radius `a`, the probability of a random point within a circle of radius `r` being within the circle of radius `a` is `pi*a^2 / pi*r^2` = `(a/r)^2`.

`arc4random` gives us a uniformly distributed random number, but we want one which is biased according to the distribution (cumulative probability) which we just calculated. A method exists for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

The inverse of our cumulative probability is `a = sqrt(p*(r^2))` (where `p` is within `[0 1]`). This simplifies to `a = r * sqrt( p )`. (which is what you already had, so congratulations! I calculated that needlessly)

The angle is much easier; we just need a uniform distribution within `[-pi pi)` or `[0 pi*2)`, etc.

```
float r = cRadius * sqrtf( arc4random( ) / (float) 0xFFFFFFFFul );
float angle = arc4random( ) * (float) (M_PI * 2) / (float) 0x100000000ul;
```

Note that I use `0xFFFFFFFFul` (=2^32-1, as an unsigned long just so it fits during compilation) for the inclusive range and `0x100000000ul` (=2^32) for the exclusive range. It's a tiny difference which you'd never notice, but mathematically this is the most correct way to transform the distributions.

Which randomisation function you use is up to you, but `arc4random` is generally recommended in Objective C, because it doesn't need seeding (it will be "more random" than a distribution seeded with the current time).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use `arc4random` as others have suggested to generate two random numbers and then map those onto the ranges of R and theta. Like:

```
#import <tgmath.h>
// ...
CGFloat r = ((CGFloat)arc4random())  * cRadius / ((CGFloat)UINT32_MAX);
CGFloat theta = ((CGFloat)arc4random())  * (M_PI + M_PI) / ((CGFloat)UINT32_MAX);
CGPoint randomXY = CGPointMake(cCenter.x + r * cos(theta), cCenter.y + r * sin(theta));
```

Comment: Nice and concise, but using cos&sin instead of cosf&sinf depends upon what CGFloat is defined to be. Can be checked with CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE.

Answer (score 0):

The points on a circle of radius R and center (x0,y0) are all (x,y) such that:

x = x0 + R*cos(theta)

y = y0 + R*sin(theta)

with theta spanning from 0 to 2*PI.

If you want points that are inside the circle, you want the points:

x = x0 + r*cos(theta)

y = y0 + r*sin(theta)

with theta spanning from 0 to 2*PI and r spanning from 0 to R.

So all you need to do is generate random values for r in [0,R] and random values for theta in [0,2*PI]!

In objective-C:

```
-(CGPoint)getRandomPointInCircle:(CGPoint)cCenter radius:(float)cRadius {

// Since it's a 2D problem, you want to generate two different random numbers to have a
// uniform distribution. So generate a number in [0,R] and another between [0,2*PI],
// without forgetting to seed.
srand48(time(0));
float r = (float)(drand48()*cRadius);
float angle = (float)(drand48()*2*M_PI);

// Now use the equations above!
float x = cCenter.x + r * cosf(angle);
float y = cCenter.y + r * sinf(angle);


CCLOG(@"--> rand point: %f,%f", x, y);

return ccp(x,y);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Damn, beat me to it by a few seconds. :)

Comment: Ha yes sorry did not see it before my own attempt, it does however have a high concentration in the center, any idea there?

Comment: No it doesn't! The points are evenly distributed from center border as r is chosen uniformly between 0 (the center) and cRadius (the border)!

Comment: In other words, for any two randomly generated points, they are as likely to be at a distance 0 from the center as they are likely to be at a distance of cRadius!

Comment: @raladdin nope. This will have a high concentration at the centre of the circle. Try it and see. Then try to guess why ;)

Comment: @Dave I tried it ;) But I can not guess why (or how to fix it)

Comment: For why: imagine you only have 3 circles, of radius 1, 2 and 3. Pick one at random (1/3 chance for each), then pick a random point within it. The circle with radius 1 will have just as many points as the one of radius 3, but it is smaller, so the points will be more closely packed. As for how to fix it, see my answer for the full mathematical solution.

Comment: Yes! absolutely! Man I love this website hahah! It SHOULD actually be more likely to end up farther from the center (instead of being a uniform distribution) because the area grows non-linearily!